# Index is not redirecting to home via session.php and authentication

Tags: javascript, php, oop

HOME.php

```
<?php
   require_once './assets/php/session.php';
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($data);
?>
<a href="assets/php/logout.php">Logout</a>
```

SESSION.php

```
<?php

  session_start();
  require_once 'auth.php';
  $cuser = new Auth();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header('location:index.php');
    die;
  }

  $cemail = $_SESSION['user'];

  $data = $cuser->currentUser($cemail);

?>
```

AUTH METHOD

```
    public function currentUser($email){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email AND deleted !=0";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['email'=>$email]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $row;
    }
```

I'm trying to display all the details of user on it's home page via session.php but my index.php is not redirecting me on the same

Comment: _"Index is not redirecting to home via session.php"_ - The only redirect in the posted code is to index.php, not home. _"but my index.php is not redirecting me on the same"_ -  You haven't shown us your index.php. I'm assuming you're not including session.php in index.php though, since it would create an infinite loop (keep redirecting to itself) if the session isn't set?

Comment: No I've not included session.php in index but I've done that in another file named script.js which is connected to index

Comment: Reading your question, it's specifically asking why index isn't redirecting. The code you've posted though, as you said yourself, isn't even included in your index? What relevance does the posted code have to do with your actual issue then? Please post all _relevant_ code and explain, in detail, what the actual issue is (post the code that doesn't work as expected, explain what should happen and what currently does happen). It's currently very unclear and confusing.